# What element is forcing my width to be fixed once the screen is small enough?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, html-email

I'm trying to figure out why my HTML email is doing this:

[image]

I feel like I've made it responsive (on browsers and email clients that support media queries) since I've replaced the fixed width with percentage-based width everywhere. None of the widths of the cells/tables inside add up to more than 400 pixels and yet it gets stuck around there. Anyone want to help me find the culprit? Which element is causing the trouble?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j7y75g7t/.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            [class="width-100-pct"] { width: 100% !important; }
            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                h1, h2, p { text-align: center !important; }
                img[class="responsive-image"] { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
                [class="width-100-pct-on-mobile"] { width: 100% !important; }
                [class="width-75-pct-on-mobile"] { width: 75% !important; }
                [class="width-third-on-mobile"] { width: 33.33333% !important;}
                [class="width-25-pct-on-mobile"] { width: 25% !important; }
                [id="prequal-btn"] { width: 50% !important; height: auto !important; }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#F1F1F3" style="width:100%;">
                    <!-- TOP BLUE STRIP -->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#1B5D9B" style="width:100%;">
                                <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="605" class="width-75-pct-on-mobile">

                                        </td>
                                        <td width="195" style="text-align:right; padding: 10px;" class="width-25-pct-on-mobile">
                                            <img width="175" height="70" src="http://i.imgur.com/4O8j7xp.png?1" style="width:175px;height:70px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;" class="responsive-image"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- CONTAINED BODY -->
                    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="600" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                        <!-- HEADLINE ROW -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style='font-size: 22pt; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif, Arial; color: #000; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;'>
                                <h1 style='font-size: 22pt; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif, Arial; color: #000; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase;margin:0;'>HEADLINE</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- IMAGE-HEADLINE-SUBTEXT ROW -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style='padding:10px; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif, Arial; color: #000;border-radius:10px;' class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                                <p><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8LX3Chz.png" width="580" height="145" style="width:580px;height:145px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;" class="responsive-image"/></p>
                                <h2 style='font-size: 18pt; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif, Arial; color: #000; text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:5px;'>SUBHEADLINE</h2>
                                <p style='font-size: 10pt; line-height: 11pt; font-family: sans-serif, Arial; color: #000; font-weight:600;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                                <p style="text-align:right;" class="orange-button-holder"><a href="http://guidantfinancial.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DJmCHC4.png?1" width="107" height="27" style="width:107px;height:27px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;"/></a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- EMPTY SPACE ROW -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="600" style="width:600px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- IMAGE-HEADLINE-SUBTEXT ROW -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style='padding:10px; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif, Arial; color: #000;border-radius:10px;' class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                                <p><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1Ye4ktl.png" width="580" height="291" style="width:580px;height:291px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;" class="responsive-image"/></p>
                                <h2 style='font-size: 18pt; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif, Arial; color: #000; text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:5px;'>SUBHEADLINE</h2>
                                <p style='font-size: 10pt; line-height: 11pt; font-family: sans-serif, Arial; color: #000; font-weight:600;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                                <p style="text-align:right;" class="orange-button-holder" ><a href="http://guidantfinancial.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DJmCHC4.png?1" width="107" height="27" style="width:107px;height:27px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;"/></a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- PREQUALIFY BUTTON ROW -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="600" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align:center;" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                                <p style="margin:0; text-align:center;"><a href="https://www.guidantfinancial.com/pre-qual/business-funding" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/q6hpze5.png?1" width="288" height="55" style="width:288px;height:55px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;" id="prequal-btn"/></a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- AWARD LOGOS -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding:10px; border-radius:10px;" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="width-100-pct">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="middle" width="200" style="text-align:center;" class="width-third-on-mobile">
                                            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5OqBS39.png" width="36" height="63" style="width:36px;height:63px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="middle" width="200" style="text-align:center;" class="width-third-on-mobile">
                                            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EwNyPSW.png" width="64" height="63" style="width:64px;height:63px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;"/>
                                        </td>                                       
                                        <td valign="middle" width="200" style="text-align:center;" class="width-third-on-mobile">
                                            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wZjpm07.png" width="89" height="63" style="width:89px;height:63px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;"/>
                                        </td>                                       
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- PHONE NUMBER -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="600" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                                <p style='text-align:left;font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;color:#939598;margin:0;font-weight:bold;'>The Guidant Team</p>
                                <p style='text-align:left;font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;margin:0;font-weight:bold;'><a href="tel:888-472-4455" style='color:#1e70b8;text-decoration:underline;font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;font-weight:bold;'>888.472.4455</a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Disclaimer -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="600" style="padding:20px 100px;text-align:center;font-family: sans-serif, Arial; font-size: 9pt; color:#000;font-weight:bold;" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
                                <p style="text-align:center;font-family: sans-serif, Arial; font-size: 9pt; color:#000; margin:0; font-weight:bold;">Guidant Financial | 1100 112th Ave NE Ste 100 | Bellevue, WA 98004</p>
                                <p style="text-align:center;font-family: sans-serif, Arial; font-size: 9pt; color:#000; margin:0; font-weight:bold;">This email was sent by MitchellLarsen@guidantfinancial.com. If you no longer want to receive these emails you may unsubscribe at any time.</p>
                            </td>
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? What email client are you seeing this issue in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first of all clean up the code and create a separate CSS file and define classes and their styles there.

Then:
You have several width properties assigned to elements that overlap / overwrite each other and then enforce that override with "!important".

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="600" class="width-100-pct-on-mobile">
```

It is bad practice to overwrite parameters with "!important" all the time.

One idea to do this is to put everything a container element that has 100% and a padding.
The cards then can be 100% width and centered and they will then be fully responsive.

An important thing to remember is when you want to center floating, responsive elements with unknown (percentage ) size is that you have to create wrapping "helper" elements, like such:

```
.centerWrapper {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;  
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and then HTML

```
<div class="centerWrapper">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="card">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I made a fiddle for you which shows this very roughly.
It shows a fluid / responsive layout based on percentages without the need for and media queries breakpoints. You can still add @media breakpoints, to change font-sizes, for example.

https://jsfiddle.net/yphfgx51/2/

Comment: I know everything you mentioned. The reason I can't do it is because I'm writing an HTML email and email clients support only a bare minimum of properties.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood your question. So, this was no help at all? Should I delete?